# Angular directive class not being applied

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Using element.addClass doesn't add the class onto the element. If I remove `class="progress-radial progress-{{percentage}}"` from the template it does however work.

Not sure what exactly is going wrong as the code fires correctly, just doesn't seem to want to add a new class if the attribute already exists.

```
angular.module(moduleName, [])
.directive('npProgress', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      percentage: '@'
    },
    template: '<div class="progress-radial progress-{{percentage}}">' +
    '<div class="overlay">{{percentage}}</div>' +
    '</div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      if ( scope.percentage > 50 ) {
        element.addClass('progress-radial--positive');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: use `angular.element(element).addClass('progress-radial--positive');`

Comment: Seems CSS priority rule issue.

Comment: Still doesn't work. If I console.log 'element' out if returns it correctly `[div.progress-radial.progress-{{percentage}}.progress-radial--positiv‌​e]` however in devtools it still shows `class="progress-radial progress-55"`

Comment: Why not use ngClass and bind a property of your directives scope?

Comment: ok use, `parseInt(scope.percentage) > 50 `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the interpolated class with the `ng-class` directive.

> ERRONEOUS
>
> ```
> //AVOID interpolated class
> template: '<div class="progress-radial progress-{{percentage}}">' +
>                '<div class="overlay">{{percentage}}</div>' +
>           '</div>',
> ```

USE `ng-class="'progress-'+percentage"`:

```
template: '<div class="progress-radial" ' +
                'ng-class="' +"'progress-'" + '+percentage">' +
              '<div class="overlay">{{percentage}}</div>' +
          '</div>',
```

The binding of the interpolated string was fighting the changes by the custom directive.

This is a Known Issue

> ### Known Issues
>
> **Dynamically changing an interpolated value**
>
> You should avoid dynamically changing the content of an interpolated string (e.g. attribute value or text node). Your changes are likely to be overwriten, when the original string gets evaluated.

--[AngularJS Developer Guide -- Interpolation -- Known Issues](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#known-issues)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the class using `angular.element`

[Here is the Documentation.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Also use **`parseInt`** on `scope.percentage` since you are sending **`string percentage`** using **`@`** binding.

**parseInt converts the string to integer and then compares.**

```
angular.module(moduleName, [])
.directive('npProgress', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      percentage: '@'
    },
    template: '<div class="progress-radial progress-{{percentage}}">' +
    '<div class="overlay">{{percentage}}</div>' +
    '</div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      if ( parseInt(scope.percentage) > 50 ) {
        angular.element(element).addClass('progress-radial--positive‌​');

      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: use `parseInt` on the `scope.percentage`